# How to correctly P/Invoke this function?

Tags: c#, pinvoke

How to correctly P/Invoke this function?

```
const char * GetReplyTo(const char * pszInText, char * pszOutText, int len)
```

I've tried to do it this way and got access violation exception:

```
[DllImport("SmartBot.dll", EntryPoint = "GetReplyTo")]
public static extern IntPtr GetReplyTo([In] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string pszInText, IntPtr pszOutText, int len);

// somewhere below:
IntPtr pbuf = GCHandle.Alloc(new byte[1000], GCHandleType.Pinned).AddrOfPinnedObject();
GetReplyTo("hi", pbuf, 2);
```

**UPDATE**
Here is pascal header for this file:

```
 {***************************************************************************
 * SmartBot Engine - Boltun source code,
 * SmartBot Engine Dynamic Link Library
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2003 ProVirus,
 * Created Alexander Kiselev Voronezh, Russia
 ***************************************************************************
 SmartBot.pas : Header Pascal for SmartBot Engine.
 }

unit SmartBot;

interface

{
function GetReplyTo(const InText: PChar; OutText: PChar; Len: integer): PChar;stdcall;export;
function LoadMind(MindFile: PChar): integer;stdcall;export;
function SaveMind(MindFile: PChar): integer;stdcall;export;
}
function GetReplyTo(const InText: PChar; OutText: PChar; Len: integer): PChar;stdcall;external 'smartbot.dll' name 'GetReplyTo';
function LoadMind(MindFile: PChar): integer;stdcall;external 'smartbot.dll' name 'LoadMind';
function SaveMind(MindFile: PChar): integer;stdcall;external 'smartbot.dll' name 'SaveMind';

implementation
end.
```

**UPDATE 2** It works. Looks like I messed up with initialization function. It returns 1 on success and 0 on fail. Weird.

Comment: Your question contains insufficient information. In particular it doesn't state anything about the ownership of data pointed to by the return value.

Comment: I don't know that either. I just trying to import dll and then will fugure out how to use it correctly using debugger

Comment: Is the return value the same as the 'out' value?

Comment: So you don't even have documentation for the function you're calling? :( But at least if leppie's guess is alway correct the return value is no problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably don't want an `IntPtr` here. You're making way too much work for yourself. For an output string parameter, you should use `StringBuilder`. You'll probably need to specify `CharSet` on your P/Invoke declaration, since the function appears to use one byte per character.

```
[DllImport("SmartBot.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern string GetReplyTo(string pszInText,
    StringBuilder pszOutText, int len);

var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(1000);
GetReplyTo("hi", stringBuilder, stringBuilder.Capacity);
```

Also make sure you're specifying the right calling convention (the `CallingConvention` property on the `DllImport` attribute).

Comment: It's not clear what the return value is and how it should be marshalled. Since it doesn't appear to be used I would prefer to declare the function as returning `IntPtr` as a means to tell the pinvoke marshaller to leave it alone.

Answer (score 3):

you should use a StringBuilder for the second parameter that you initialize to size len